# RetroPie - I can't see the NES emulator

Tags: setup, retropie

I installed RetroPie onto my Raspberry Pi, and booted it up.

I did not see any console systems available to me, only old computers.

So I read on, and figured that if I install the rom files according to: [Transferring ROMs](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/Transferring-Roms), that my NES might actually show up on screen!

SO I tried that.  I loaded up my usb stick with ROMs (after following their instructions about creating a RetroPie folder and having their system generate the folder structure, then adding my ROMs into the NES folder) and put it into my Raspberry Pi.

No love.  RetroPie booted up again, theoretically copied the rom files, but I still can't see the NES folder.  What should I do?  How can I get this system to appear?

Comment: how about accepting the offered answer or clarify/state the problem even further?

Answer (score 3):

SSH into the machine and navigate to the roms dir at

```
/home/pi/RetroPie/roms/snes/
```

and verify if the files are there.

If not, scp them in.

From a windows machine, best use a tool like **winscp** for this.

A restart of EmulationStation could help to re-index the roms.
Do note that the roms have to be of the correct file extension. (can also be a zip file for SNES)